# Improve the Conditional structure?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a script that checks the current url in the browser and acts accordingly, my code is as follow :

```
if (url.match("^https?://(www\.)?bing\..+$")) {
    engine = "bing";
} else {
    if (url.match("^https?://(www\.)?google\..+$"))
        engine = "google";
    else
    if (url.match("^https?://(www\.)?yahoo\..+$"))
        engine = "yahoo";
    else .... // etc.
}
```

and so on for 8 website, i just keep with the if else, is there a way to improve this code, cuz it looks to me dumb.

Comment: Map engines to their regexes and loop.

Comment: would you give me a little example, i am a little newbie in Javascript ^^;
thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can get the match position in your variable for the piece of the url that you are looking for.

Like so:

```
url = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.yahoo.com']

for (var i = 0; i<url.length; i++ )
{
    var site = url[i].match("^https?://(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9]+)\..+$")[2]
    alert(site)
}
```

And with that in hand you can switch it to do whatever you are attempting to:

```
switch(site) {
     case "google": { /* do something..*/ } break;
     case "yahoo" : { /* do something..*/ } break;
}
```

Follows the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XPT3L/

Comment: EXACTLY WHAT I NEEDED :D
Thanks a lot **Roger**, with the switch and all.

Answer (score 3):

Put your engines in an array and loop,

something like this

```
   sengs = ['bing','google','yahoo'];
   foreach of yourarray {
        if(url.match("^https?://(www\.)?"+your value+"\..+$")){
            engine = your value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just grab the domain name from the url using `match` on the url? It would make your code a lot shorter and you don't need to write the *almost*-same check every time.

```
var engine = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^\.]+)/)[1];
```

This piece only grabs the first word after the protocol, which is `www` for most websites. to make sure you grab the correct name you could wrap this in a function with an extra check:

```
function getDomainName(url) {
    url = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1].split('.');
    return url[url.length - 2].toLowerCase();
}
```

Calling `getDomainName(url)` would now return the domain name, which you could use later.

```
getDomainName('http://bing.com/'); // bing
getDomainName('http://www.google.com/'); // google
getDomainName('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380805/improve-the-conditional-structure/'); // stackoverflow
// and so on
```

Now you just need to check if this value is inside an array of engined you accept. This could be done using `Array.indexof`.

```
var engines = ['google', 'bing', 'yahoo'];
var domain = getDomainName(url);

if (engines.indexOf(domain) > -1) {
    engine = domain;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Now you've got your engine name, use this in a switch-case (or if statements if you like these better) and do what you want to do. You can get rid of the engines array if you do this.

Putting all this together, this code is ALL you need:

```
function getDomainName(url) {
    url = url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1].split('.');
    return url[url.length - 2].toLowerCase();
}

switch (getDomainName(url)) {
  case "google":
    // do stuff for google's engine.
    break;

  case "bing":
    // Do Bing stuff.
    break;

  case "yahoo":
    // and so on
    break;

  default:
    // None of the engines was found
    break;
}
```

Comment: I was not clear in my Question, I am sorry, yeah that is a great idea, but i for each engine, i have to do something different. Although the wrapping in a function is a great idea, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @user2463937 you were completely clear. This simply replaces the checks for getting the domain at one go, instead of for every case. I'll add something to show you how you could use this in a switch case.

Comment: @user2463937 You're welcome. I just edited it a little bit again, the last block of code could eventually be copy-pasted now.